# I Need Tips to make my PHP password work

Tags: php, html, forms

I have trouble with these codes:

password.php:

```
    <html>

 <head>

    <title>Password!</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

 </head>

 <body>

    <ul>

    <form action="check.php" method="POST">

        <li><input type="password" name="no1" placeholder="enter your password"></li>
        <li><input type="submit" value="GO!"></li>

    </form>

    </ul>

 </body>
```

Here is password2.php:

```
    <html>

 <head>

    <title>Password!</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

 </head>

 <body>

    <ul>

    <form action="check.php" method="POST">

        <li><input type="password" name="name" placeholder="verify your password"></li>
        <li><input type="submit" value="GO!"></li>

    </form>

    </ul>

 </body>
```

And here is check.php:

```
    <?php

$enter = $_POST['no1'];

if (empty($enter)) {
    echo "Please enter password!";
}

if (!(empty($enter))) {
    echo "Your password is $enter";
}


?>

<html>
<body>
<p><a href="password2.php">Move on!</a></p>
</body>
</html>

<?php

$check = $_POST['name'];

if ($check == $enter) {
    echo "Acces Granted";
}

if (!($check == $enter)) {
    echo "Acces denied!";
}

?>
```

The troubles I have are:

- check.php doesn't recognise "name" from password2.php
- And I can't verify the password

Comment: It would not work because $_POST is not persistent from one request to another. When you are submitting from password2.php there is no $enter.

Comment: Thanks! So i must have another check.php right?

Comment: I think is better. But you also need the value for the first password. But why aren't you sending both passwords in a single form in a single request?

Comment: Because one is to enter and the other is to verify, i thought i could make it survey style, which flows on...

Comment: How do i transmit the value of no1 from password.php to check2.php?

Comment: Put it in the session variable. `$_SESSION['no1'] = 'value';`. More info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $_POST variable is not persistent between requests it would not work. You can store the value from first form in the $_SESSION variable and retrieve it from session.

More info about php sessions [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Leave everything as it is in your question except `check.php`, here is the modified one:

```
           <?php

            //starting the session in PHP
            session_start();

            $enter = null;

            // this is all the logic you need for retrieving `no1` from POST or SESSION 
            if (isset($_POST['no1'])){
                $enter = $_POST['no1'];
                $_SESSION['no1'] = $enter;
            }elseif(isset($_SESSION['no1'])){
                $enter = $_SESSION['no1'];
            }




            if (empty($enter)) {
                echo "Please enter password!";
            }

            if (!(empty($enter))) {
                echo "Your password is $enter";
            }


            ?>

                <html>
                <body>
                <p><a href="password2.php">Move on!</a></p>
                </body>
                </html>

            <?php

            $check = $_POST['name'];

            if ($check == $enter) {
                echo "Acces Granted";

                // you can comment the next line if you are debugging,
                // but after that you should destroy de session so you don't have a password as plain text
                session_destroy();
            }

            if (!($check == $enter)) {
                echo "Acces denied!";
            }

            ?>
```

Comment: I don't understand how can i apply it to the code, i read your suggestion and link but could you please give me a demonstration. Many Thanks!

Comment: Just as a suggestion, if you are learning PHP this code is fine but you want to put it the production please have a look at a PHP framework, for example Laravel.